# Typescript safely implement type dependent function

Tags: typescript

I am trying to safely implement the following function

```
type OneOrAll<T extends any[]> =
    T extends { length: 1 } ? T[0] :
    T

interface Foo {
  // ...
}

declare function oneOrAll<A extends Foo[]>(...as: A): OneOrAll<A>;
```

which should either return `Foo` or `Foo[]` depending on the length of the given parameters. For example

```
const x: Foo = oneOrAll(fooA);
const xs: Foo[] = oneOrAll(fooA, fooB);
```

The types work out already, but I am struggling to write the implementation. My first attempt was this

```
function oneOrAll<A extends Foo[]>(...as: A): OneOrAll<A> {
    if (as.length == 1) {
        return as[0]; // Type 'Foo' is not assignable to type 'OneOrAll<A>'.
    }
    return as; // Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'OneOrAll<A>'.
               //   Type 'Foo[]' is not assignable to type 'OneOrAll<A>'.
}
```

however this does not compile with the inlined errors. What is the proper way to implement this function?

Comment: Unresolved conditional types (ie those that still contain type parameters) will often require type assertions. Don't think there is a way around it. You could use overloads instead

Comment: side note: using `as` as an identifier in TypeScript is unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use function overriding to implement your function:

```
function oneOrAll<A extends [Foo]>(x: A[0]): A[0]
function oneOrAll<A extends Foo[]>(...xs: A): A
function oneOrAll<A extends Foo[]>(...xs: A): A[0] | A {
    if (xs.length === 1) {
        return xs[0]
    }
    return xs
}
```

You get the following result:

```
declare const foo: Foo
const x = oneOrAll(foo) // Foo
const y = oneOrAll(foo, foo) // [Foo, Foo]
```